# something is wrong in my RelativeLayout example

Tags: android-layout

I am novice and trying to create programmatically:

[image]

But my program shows the following for now:
[image]

My code is here:

```
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    layout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFDD);

    TextView tView = new TextView(this);
    tView.setText("TITLE");
    tView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,34);
    tView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFEEEE66);
    tView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tView.setId(100);
    layout.addView(tView);

    View line = new View(this);
    line.setId(150);
    line.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,5 ));
    line.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams150 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams150.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,100);
    layout.addView(line,layoutParams150);

    TextView tView2 = new TextView(this);
    tView2.setId(200);
    tView2.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    tView2.setText("NAME1");
    tView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,34);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams200 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams200.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,150);
    layout.addView(tView2,layoutParams200);
```

I don't understand why "tView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);" does not work.
I don't understand why I can't draw the line.
BTW what is the best way to create such screen programmatically?
Thanks.

Comment: Re: "what is the best way to create such screen programmatically". Actually, you generally want to use XML layout files to do as much of the screen layout as possible. That will keep your code much cleaner and easier to read, and allows you to make use of nice GUI tools that are available in all Android IDEs.

Comment: Okay. I will write on XML. It's really  more easy. Thanks.